# required mongoose validator not working for insertMany?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Model schema:

```
let mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    area: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    dateUpdated: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    data: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    },
    fileName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    datetimeCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    },
    dateTimeDeleted: {
        type: Date
    }
}, {
    collection: 'my_collection'
});
```

Sample data to insert:

```
[{
    area: 'Some Area',
    // I'm forcing it to be undefined if the data was not provided in attempt to fix the problem, 
    // but it just gets stored as null
    dateUpdated: undefined,
    data: {
      key1: 1,
      key2: 2
    },
    fileName: 'sample-file.xlsx',
    datetimeCreated: 2021-03-03T09:10:51.966Z,
  }
];
```

Insert:

```
let myModel = new MyModel();
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    myModel.collection.insertMany(sortedData, (err) => { ... } });
```

The process is that you upload an Excel file and there's a column for `dateUpdated` but if the user left that blank it should return an error when they try to upload the file.

What happens right now is the whole thing still gets uploaded, with `dateUpdated` just set to `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honest mistake.

Instead of using:

```
let myModel = new MyModel();
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    myModel.collection.insertMany(sortedData, (err) => { ... } });
```

I had to do:

```
// Not needed --> let myModel = new MyModel();
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Remove .collection
    myModel.insertMany(sortedData, (err) => { ... } });
```